# Como chamar um novo terminal à partir de um shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

Gostaria de saber como chamar um novo terminal/xterm de dentro de um comando no shell script, de forma com que o shell script que chamou o outro script continue executando sem parar.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Obrigado @QMechanic73

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando o [`GNOME`](http://br.gnome.org/GNOMEBR/Gnome) como interface, poderá chamar um novo terminal chamando o [`gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html), veja um exemplo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

readonly OUTRO_SCRIPT="hello1.sh"; # O script a ser executado

chmod +x $OUTRO_SCRIPT;
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./$OUTRO_SCRIPT; exec $SHELL";

#Continua a execução do script

echo "Foo... ";
echo "....Bar";
```

Para chamar o [`Terminal Emulator - xterm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm):

```
xterm
```

Ou:

```
x-terminal-emulator
```

Se estiver utilizando [`XFCE`](http://www.xfce.org/) como interface, poderá chamar o terminal executando o [`xfce4-terminal`](https://launchpad.net/xfce4-terminal):

```
xfce4-terminal
```

Se estiver utilizando [`KDE`](https://br.kde.org/) como interface, poderá chamar o terminal executando o [`Konsole`](https://userbase.kde.org/Konsole):

```
Konsole
```

Se estiver utilizando [`LXDE`](http://wiki.lxde.org/pt/P%C3%A1gina_principal) como interface, poderá chamar o terminal executando o [`LXTerminal`](http://wiki.lxde.org/pt/LXTerminal):

```
lxterminal
```

[**Aqui**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) você poderá encontrar algumas informações referente ao *Terminal* que podem ser úteis.

Answer (score 1):

Para chamar um comando em background (continuar rodando sem parar), você usa o comando **nohup [comando] &** para chamar o programa ou script.

```
 nohup [./script.sh] &
```

Nesse caso, as saidas do programa, continuarão sendo mostrada no terminal que chamou. Para que isso não aconteça, vc deve redireciona-la para /dev/null.

```
nohup [./scrip.sh] > /dev/null &
```

Ou talvez vc queira redirecionar para um arquivo de log.

```
nohup [./script.sh] > ./saida.log &
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

boa noite!

Não necessariamente precisa de outro terminal, pode realizar a execução de vários scripts ao mesmo tempo.

Crie os dois arquivos de script, no exemplo irei informar como se fosse index.sh e variaveis.sh

No arquivo index.sh irá puxar o arquivo variaveis.sh da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./variaveis.sh # Executa e lê variáveis, funções, etc.

echo $var1
```

e no arquivo variaveis.sh irá definir todas as variaveis:

variaveis.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="Esta variavel vem de outro arquivo!"
```

Os dois arquivos devem ter permissão de execução então será necessário executar

chmod +x index.sh

chmod +x variaveis.sh

Execute o arquivo index.sh e veja a mágica acontecer.

```
$ ./index.sh
```

--EOF--

Answer (score -1):

## Cabeçalhos

Simples, digite a linha de comando abaixo:

**gnome-terminal -- ./exemplo.sh**

Ou caso seu script esteja em um local especifico digite o caminho:

**gnome-terminal -- Desktop/./exemplo.sh**

Legenda:

"gnome-terminal" -> chama um novo terminal

"--" -> manda executar o programa ou script

"Desktop/.exemplo.sh -> caminho onde está o script ou programa

Comment: E o que sua resposta agrega perante a resposta do stderr? Ou do Everton?